# How do I make onPress remember it was pressed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, sorting

How do I make pressedItem be remembered and not changed on next onPress, to make it deselect if only the function is called again? Perhaps the ids to be remembered in an array and the array alters its length between pressedItem and dePressedItem?

```
  const [pressedItem, setPressedItem] = useState(null);
let selected = [];
  const changeColor = (itemid) => {
    setPressedItem(itemid);
}

  };
```

```
  <FlatGrid data={interesi}
    style={tw``}
    spacing={10}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => changeColor(item.id)}>
      <View style={ pressedItem === item.id ? item.firstStyle : item.secondStyle }>
        <Text style={tw`text-black`}>{item.english}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

If no other ID can be pressed you can use:

```
const changeColor = (itemid) => {
    if (!pressedItem) {
        setPressedItem(itemid);
    }
};
```

If you are looking to not press the same id as before then:

```
const changeColor = (itemid) => {
    if (pressedItem !== itemid) {
        setPressedItem(itemid);
    }
};
```

EDIT:

Updating the answer based on comments. Then you would need to do something like holding a map of the pressed state of the `itemid`:

```
const [pressedItems, setPressedItems] = useState({});
let selected = [];

const changeColor = (itemid) => {
    pressedItems[itemid] = !pressedItems[itemid];
    setPressedItem(pressedItems);
};
```

Comment: I am looking to be able to press the same ID, so then it deselects (is no longer a pressedItem) and to be able to when pressed more than one IDs, all of them to stay pressedItem, not to switch when the second one is pressed.

Comment: I need pressedItem to store its ID somehow. Probably in an array, but I can't figure out how

Comment: Having a map based on the state `itemid` would be faster than searching through an array

Answer (score 0):

You should add the id of your item to an array as you said:

```
const [pressedIds, setPressedIds] = useState<number[]>([]);

const isMyIdPressed = (id: number) => {
  if (pressedIds.include(id)) {
    setPressedIds(pressedIds.splice(pressedIds.indexOf(id), 1));
  } else {
    setPressedIds([...pressedIds, id]);
  }
}

<FlatGrid data={interesi}
    style={tw``}
    spacing={10}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => isMyIdPressed(item.id)}>
      <View style={pressedIds.include(item.id) ? item.firstStyle : item.secondStyle }>
        <Text style={tw`text-black`}>{item.english}</Text>
```

Whenever you press an id, just check if it is in the array, if yes add the id to the array and if no remove it from the array.

Comment: Do you mind rewriting the code I have supplied above, since I can't quite understand the
const [pressedIds, setPressedIds] = useState<number[]>([]);

Comment: I have edited my answer so it matches what you want

Comment: I get an error when I use  const [pressedIds, setPressedIds] = useState<number[]>([]); on <number[]> (Unexpected token)
Was I supposed to change <number[]> with something?

Comment: You can just keep `useState([]);` but it shouldn't return an error anyway